# How can we update delta item from one Sitecore instance(master DB) to another Sitecore Instance(master db)

Tags: powershell-extensions

We want to move delta items update done within a time interval from one sitecore instance to another using Sitecore Powershell script, is there a way to connect to 2 master DBs at once and copy/move all updated items from one instance to another within a time interval. Doing the same using packages is very tedious and time taking. We want to automate the process.

Comment: Configure the second master db as you would any others then you can connect to it like `Get-Item "master2:\content\home"`

Comment: @MichaelWest Just adding master2 to connectionstring.config file will I be able to access that database or i need to perform any other step for this.

Comment: I think the steps are like adding a new publishing target. https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/02/how-to-add-new-publishing-target-in.html

Comment: @MichaelWest Is there a way to create package from master2 database with package name as master, as we are not able to install the package directly from master2 to master.

Comment: If master2 and master are connected to the same running instance of Sitecore, using a package would be unnecessary. Out of the box you can move content between databases.

Comment: @MichaelWest We are using blue/green approach during our deployments and while deployment the changes done on green, we need to move them to blue master database. It is very time consuming. I am looking for a faster sloution where I can directly move udpated items from one database to another. I was trying remote scripting as well but it did not worked on Azure Paas Sitecore instances.

Comment: @MichaelWest I am trying with Remote scripting, I am able to connect to azure sitecore instance using Windows powershell, but when I am trying to connect using Sitecore ISE or Sitecore Powershell command line it is not working. I am getting below error.
Import-Module : The current provider (Sitecore) cannot open a file.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module -Name SPE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.\SPE.psm1:String) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand